# Python can't connect to mongodb-replSet

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I have a mongodb-replSet called `replicaSetOne` and it has 2 members.

192.168.0.1 -PRIMARY-

192.168.0.2 -SECONDARY-

Now I have worked on my pyton-skills and in my app I have a simple connectionstring:

`mongoConnection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017/", serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10, connectTimeoutMS=20000)`

All worked fine. But then `192.168.0.1` rebooted and the `192.168.0.2` became PRIMARY and this is where things got strange.

- First of all, the Database on `192.168.0.1` is now behind, and not a little bit but ~1GB ... the db-size on PRIMARY is now 19,9GB and on the SECONDARY 19GB.
- Once a day it happens, that I start my app and everything is fine(!?) I can see in my app the latest entrys, so they have to come from the PRIMARY because if the SECONDARY is ~1GB behind, the data could not be there. The connectionString hasn't changed so the server-discovery-magic must be handled my pymongo automaticly. "dafuq" I thought and I made a simple script to re-test it:

..

```
import pymongo 

mongoConnection = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017/', serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10, connectTimeoutMS=20000)
mongoDb = mongoConnection["myLiveData"]

# get all collections
filter = {"name": {"$regex": r"^(?!system\.)"}}
allCollections = mongoDb.list_collection_names(filter=filter)

for c in allCollections:     
    print(c)
```

..

- Now I get a Error:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members
> match selector "Primary()", Timeout: 0.01s, Topology Description:
> <TopologyDescription id: 637ebee9a3dcd68482e354aa, topology_type:
> ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('192.168.0.2',
> 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>, <ServerDescription
> ('192.168.0.1', 27017) server_type: RSSecondary, rtt:
> 0.06199999999989814>]>

Everything I tried from now on, except connecting to the new PRIMARY directly, failed. I tried every example on the internet, nothing works. For example: when I put a Array of connections into the call like

`pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017/,mongodb://@192.168.0.2:27017/?replicaSet=replicaSetOne')`

or

`pymongo.MongoClient(['mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017/','mongodb://@192.168.0.2:27017/'], replicaSet='replicaSetOne')`

etc.

Even when I now start my app that worked before, it doesn't work anymore(!)

So how do I connect correctly to a mongo-replicaSet in Python? Maybe someone has a working code-example?

Comment: Have you tried the [format for replica sets](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples)? `mongodb://192.168.0.1:27017,192.168.0.2:27017/?replicaSet=replicaSetOne` Also, size on disk isn't a good representation for how synchronized the nodes are

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried that, it results with an error, saying, that multiple host-urls are not allowed (?). For the size-issue.. ok, but 1GB ??